# Text not appearing on XTS plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

I'm having trouble adding some text to an plot of time series data in R using **xts**. I've produced a simple example of the problem.

My `text()` command seems to do nothing, whereas I can add a points to the plot. I've tried to keep the code simple by using defaults where possible

```
require(quantmod)

# fetch the data and plot it using default options
getSymbols('MKS.L')
plot(MKS.L$MKS.L.Close)

# try to add text - doesn't appear
text(as.Date('2012-01-01'),y=500,"wobble", cex=4)

# add a point - this does appear
testPos <- xts(600, as.Date('2012-01-01'))
points( testPos, pch = 3, cex = 4, col = "red" )
```

Any help appreciated - I'm pretty new to R and I've spent hours on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but the `plot.xts` function that comes with the `xts` package is not fully developed.

You're much better off using `plot.zoo` or `plot.xts` from the [xtsExtra](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118) package (which was written as a Google Summer of Code project with the intention being to roll it into the xts package)

Either of these will work:

```
plot(as.zoo(MKS.L$MKS.L.Close))
text(as.Date('2012-01-01'),y=500,"wobble", cex=4)

#install.packages("xtsExtra", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
xtsExtra::plot.xts(MKS.L$MKS.L.Close)
text(as.Date('2012-01-01'),y=500,"wobble", cex=4)
```

Comment: When I use `xtsEstra::plot.xts` or `plot.zoo` then I get the text displayed on the graph which is great. Using `plot.xts` doesn't produce any change - which I suppose is to be expected as I assume the plot call is delegated to `plot.xts` However, with `xtsEstra::plot.xts` and `plot.zoo` methods now the `points()` call further down doesn't draw anything?

Comment: @JohnO `points(as.Date("2012-01-01"), 600, pch = 3, cex = 4, col = "red" )`

Comment: That `points` call works, thanks. I've been messing about with the various `plot` calls and I'm getting very weird results. Both the `plot(as.zoo(...))` and `plot.zoo(...)` calls always work, so far so good. However, the calls `plot.xts(...)` and `xtsEstra::plot.xts(..)` don't work in a clean environment (e.g. new R instance), but they do work after you perform a `plot(as.zoo(...))` or `plot.zoo(...)` call in the environment ... weird! Anyway, moral of the story is use either `plot(as.zoo(...))` and `plot.zoo(...)`. Thanks again.