# Text annotation in xts plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series, xts

I'm plotting predicted and observed returns from an xts file over each other.
I've been trying to use the text() function, but it's failing as my x-coordinate needs a time-based value to plot it. I'm trying to annotate the RMSE & Accuracy values of each model onto each plot.

I'm not using autoplot.zoo() or ggplot2 but rather the S3 method for xts.

Any possible help is highly appreciated.

Example of plot:
[image: SVM plot of predicted vs observed Log returns]

Reproducible example of 30 observations:

```
df.predicted <- structure(list(sp500 = c(0.00308633599736579, -0.0102945228811291, 
0.00272233430531683, -0.0177826247734551, 0.00185037721178295, 
0.00729660312665625, 0.0035578290234174, 0.00332004914966584, 
0.00991542270601058, -0.00602436721304404, 0.0065746732040209, 
0.000327323231059243, 0.00916120966953751, 0.00261789271484347, 
-0.00195588307773482, 0.00300799720194303, -0.0102309926490593, 
0.000652487806356518, 0.00304855048996754, 0.00022826707346593, 
0.00610922625203322, 0.00521084483841704, 0.00692053716928683, 
0.00687297232034695, 0.00446858940132962, 0.0016906968757511, 
-0.00640887732008148, 0.010055598145355, -0.00824235478795256, 
-0.0119505384705456), SVM = c(0.0084652756742501, -0.00528251903114062, 
-0.00528058370312449, 0.0042162911593202, -0.00867227417970532, 
-0.00573439344139216, 0.00189984978464037, 0.0010723209869716, 
0.00602634583657307, 0.00195405519365384, 0.00799871931241332, 
-0.000381055826348525, 0.0086327120285207, 0.000236221915013065, 
-0.00119454332199379, 0.010644620802126, -0.000593540960202922, 
-0.00534767860559181, -0.00540458388523374, 0.00311027237695335, 
0.00174002505960733, -0.00188187724218377, 0.0103728117264802, 
0.00190612474961373, 0.00871609815852685, 9.79783217687676e-05, 
-0.00880817328548864, 0.00474787674193693, -0.00711663449138695, 
-0.00653882507699522)), row.names = c("2003-07-31", "2003-08-01", 
"2003-08-04", "2003-08-05", "2003-08-06", "2003-08-07", "2003-08-08", 
"2003-08-11", "2003-08-12", "2003-08-13", "2003-08-14", "2003-08-15", 
"2003-08-18", "2003-08-19", "2003-08-20", "2003-08-21", "2003-08-22", 
"2003-08-25", "2003-08-26", "2003-08-27", "2003-08-28", "2003-08-29", 
"2003-09-01", "2003-09-02", "2003-09-03", "2003-09-04", "2003-09-05", 
"2003-09-08", "2003-09-09", "2003-09-10"), class = "data.frame")

time <- c("2003-07-31", "2003-08-01", 
"2003-08-04", "2003-08-05", "2003-08-06", "2003-08-07", "2003-08-08", 
"2003-08-11", "2003-08-12", "2003-08-13", "2003-08-14", "2003-08-15", 
"2003-08-18", "2003-08-19", "2003-08-20", "2003-08-21", "2003-08-22", 
"2003-08-25", "2003-08-26", "2003-08-27", "2003-08-28", "2003-08-29", 
"2003-09-01", "2003-09-02", "2003-09-03", "2003-09-04", "2003-09-05", 
"2003-09-08", "2003-09-09", "2003-09-10")

plotit <- function(expression,activation){
  abc <- cbind(xts(expression, order.by = as.POSIXct(time)), xts(df.predicted$sp500, order.by = as.POSIXct(time)))
  plot(abc[,2], col=alpha("black",0.85), lwd=2, main=paste0(activation))
  lines(abc[,1], col=alpha("red",0.65))
}

plotit(df.predicted$SVM, "SVM")
```

Comment: please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @phiver I have now provided an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plot.xts is still not completely developed. But there is a nifty little package called rtsplot that can handle timeseries (and ohlc timeseries). This works on base graphics and you can modify everything you like. I included an example below where everything is incorporated in your `plotit` function.

```
library(xts)
library(scales)
library(rtsplot)


plotit <- function(expression, activation, textlocation, what_text){
  abc <- cbind(xts(df.predicted$SVM, order.by = as.POSIXct(time)), xts(df.predicted$sp500, order.by = as.POSIXct(time)))
  rtsplot(abc[,2], col=alpha("black",0.85), lwd=2, main=paste0(activation))
  rtsplot.lines(abc[,1], col=alpha("red",0.65)) # add second line
  rtsplot.text(abc[textlocation], what_text, col = "red") # add text based on rownumber.
}

plotit(df.predicted$SVM, "SVM", 25, "text goes here")
```

[image]

**edit based on comment:**

Use `text(x = as.POSIXct("2003-08-28"), y = -0.01, labels = "RSquared = 0.5", cex=2)` inside the plotit function and it works. The graph is created inside the function and plot.new call has been called inside the plot.it's environment and not in the global environment. That is why it is not working when you call `text` after using plotit.

```
plotit <- function(expression,activation){
  abc <- cbind(xts(expression, order.by = as.POSIXct(time)), xts(df.predicted$sp500, order.by = as.POSIXct(time)))
  plot(abc[,2], col=alpha("black",0.85), lwd=2, main=paste0(activation))
  lines(abc[,1], col=alpha("red",0.65))
  text(x = as.POSIXct("2003-08-28"), y = -0.01, labels = "RSquared = 0.5", cex=2)
}
```

Adjust the function code to make the function accept the variables needed for the legend and you can do it in one call.

[image]

Comment: I did what you indicated, but the console still gives me the `Error in text.default(x = as.POSIXct("2003-08-28"), y = -0.01, labels = "RSquared = 0.5",  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet


Called from: text.default(x = as.POSIXct("2003-08-28"), y = -0.01, labels = "RSquared = 0.5", cex=2)`

Comment: @PrinzvonK, that is weird, because everything on my end works exactly as in my post and with your example data. Did you copy the plotit function from my example (in the edit part)?

Comment: It seems to be that there are more errors with the plot.xts function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18315837/9834582

_However, the calls plot.xts(...) and xtsEstra::plot.xts(..) don't work in a clean environment (e.g. new R instance), but they do work after you perform a plot(as.zoo(...)) or plot.zoo(...) call in the environment ... weird_

Comment: You could always use tidyquant (or timetk) to transform your xts object into a data.frame and use ggplot2 to plot everything. I tend to use either this or rtsplot as I have more control over everything I want to plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function `mtext("Text")`. As far as I understand, you should use it within your plot function (`plotit`), in order to get the text inside the graph area.